# SharePoint 2013 SP1 install error during product configuration: Step 5 Failed, timeout

Tags: sharepoint, virtual-machine, sharepoint-2013, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

I am installing `SharePoint 2013 SP1` on `Windows Server 2012 R2` and cannot get passed Step 5 on the Product configuration manager. The last successful service is the "*Document Conversions Launcher Service*" then it times out with this error: **`An exception of type System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException was thrown`**

Any ideas on getting this installed properly?

```
Windows Server 2012 R2 running on Hyper-V VM (4 cores, 12gb RAM),
SQL Server 2012, 
SharePoint 2013 SP1,
Office Professional 2013
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Registry, Add a new key named "AcknowledgedRunningOnAppServer" of DWORD type at the below mentioned locations.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\<var>version</var>\LauncherSettings
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\<var>version</var>\LoadBalancerSettings
```

Set the value to 1.

Restart the System.

Now the Configuration Wizard should work fine.

Reference - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2910363

Comment: Confirming that this works for me using the same setup as the author of the question.

Comment: Can confirm this solution too. @ItsBradMorgan, accept the answer if it was working for you.